# Does flask sql-alchemy require closing

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm getting the error: `sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30` under circumstances that I have yet to recreate consistently. This seems to usually be because people failed to release the session. Which sounds right, because I never explicitly release the session. But, unlike SqlAlchemy none of the tutorials or documentation posts I have seen for Flask-SqlAlchemy talk about closing sessions. This makes me think that Flask-SqlAlchemy has been closing my session for me. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, the session is bound to the request context if I understand correctly. You don't need to manually close the session.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense to me. I believe the deployed code leaves some requests open for way too long. So, that's likely what is going on.